# Using a particular version for golang dependency module

Tags: go, dependencies, go-modules, go-get, go-build

I'm trying to build postfix-exporter code from the [github link](https://github.com/kumina/postfix_exporter).
It has a dependency on the `go-systemd` package as mentioned in `go.mod` file `github.com/coreos/go-systemd/v22 v22.0.0`.
I see in the `go.mod` file , the mentioned version for the package is `v22.0.0.`
But when I run `go get -u` for this path, it starts downloading the latest version ( `v22.2.0`) of `go-systemd` which has an issue in the latest commit and causing failure to compile .
The error coming in that is

```
github.com/coreos/go-systemd/v22@v22.2.0/sdjournal/journal.go:313:60: error: '_SD_ARRAY_STATIC' undeclared here (not in a function) // my_sd_id128_to_string(void *f, sd_id128_t boot_id, char s[_SD_ARRAY_STATIC SD_ID128_STRING_MAX]) ^ In file included from /usr/include/systemd/sd-journal.h:31:0, from pkg/mod/github.com/coreos/go-systemd/v22@v22.2.0/sdjournal/journal.go:27: pkg/mod/github.com/coreos/go-systemd/v22@v22.2.0/sdjournal/journal.go:313:77: error: expected ']' before numeric constant // my_sd_id128_to_string(void *f, sd_id128_t boot_id, char s[_SD_ARRAY_STATIC SD_ID128_STRING_MAX])
```

I want to know , how to compile for a specific version of any dependency module if this is not the way or I'm missing some option required to honor the version of dependency packages mentioned in `go.mod`

Thanks very much in advance and please pardon my golang knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `-u`. The purpose of `-u` is to allow Go to try to upgrade you to the latest minor or patch version:

> The -u flag instructs get to update modules providing dependencies
> of packages named on the command line to use newer minor or patch
> releases when available.

If you're just trying to install dependencies, use `go get`.

Comment: thanks for respoinding
I had tried that earlier without '-u' too and it is failing with the same error .
I have not installed go instead trying to run it directly from the bin folder. 
have set the GOPATH AND GOBIN to current home directory 

 go/bin/go get github.com/kumina/postfix_exporter
# github.com/coreos/go-systemd/sdjournal
src/github.com/coreos/go-systemd/sdjournal/journal.go:1160:2: could not determine kind of name for C.my_sd_id128_to_string
cgo: 
gcc errors for preamble:
src/github.com/coreos/go-systemd/sdjournal/journal.go:313:60: error: '_SD_ARRAY_STATIC'

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to build podman for Centos7 and found this error, noticed that _SD_ARRAY_STATIC was not defined, so I just did a search in google and found this header file: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/include/systemd/_sd-common.h.html.
Also, by doing a search of this file in my docker I found this very old one: `/usr/include/systemd/_sd-common.h`, so I just decided to modify it and add that definition:

```
/*-*- Mode: C; c-basic-offset: 8; indent-tabs-mode: nil -*-*/

#ifndef foosdcommonhfoo
#define foosdcommonhfoo

/***
  This file is part of systemd.

  Copyright 2013 Lennart Poettering
...
...
#ifndef _SD_END_DECLARATIONS
#  ifdef __cplusplus
#    define _SD_END_DECLARATIONS                                \
        }                                                       \
        struct __useless_struct_to_allow_trailing_semicolon__
#  else
#    define _SD_END_DECLARATIONS                                \
        struct __useless_struct_to_allow_trailing_semicolon__
#  endif
#endif

#ifndef _SD_ARRAY_STATIC
#  if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
#    define _SD_ARRAY_STATIC static
#  else
#    define _SD_ARRAY_STATIC
#  endif
#endif

#endif
```

And voila, got it working.
TL;DR, probably you have to update systemd package or at least the systemd C library.